# Changing permissions of folder not working

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

Using Raspbian Buster, I have 2 users, The root user (pi) and a user I setup (polysense). I have a script that runs at startup that is owned by the root user. Part of the script is that it writes to a file on the polysense account. However I am getting a permissions error when the script runs.
I tried: `sudo chmod 777 configSite` as `configSite` is the folder that contains the files I need to write to.

When I view the permissions, it does not change. What am I doing wrong here?
I am expecting to see `drwxr-xr-rwx` for the files inside configSite.

```
pi@polysensesolutions:~ $ cd /home/polysense/
pi@polysensesolutions:/home/polysense $ sudo chmod 777 configSite
pi@polysensesolutions:/home/polysense $ cd configSite
pi@polysensesolutions:/home/polysense/configSite $ ls -l
total 164
-rw-r--r-- 1 root      root        1985 Sep 17 04:25 '>'
drwxr-xr-x 3 polysense polysense   4096 Sep  2 16:33  configSite
-rw-r--r-- 1 root      root      143360 Sep 17 04:25  db.sqlite3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 polysense polysense    630 Sep  2 15:51  manage.py
drwxr-xr-x 4 polysense polysense   4096 Sep  2 16:34  pages
drwxr-xr-x 2 polysense polysense   4096 Sep 17 04:12  templates
drwxr-xr-x 4 polysense polysense   4096 Sep 17 04:25  wifiApp
```

Comment: `sudo chmod 777 configSite` you're changing permissions of the directory `configSite`, but it doesn't mean files inside `configSite` will be changed. If you want to change permissions of everything inside `configSite`, you need to add option `-R` to `chmod`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you run `chmod 777 directory`, then only the permissions of the directory *itself* are changed, not the files contained within it.

If you want to change the permissions of *all* the files contained in a directory, including those in subdirectories and those subdirectories themselves, use:

```
chmod -R 777 directory
```

The `-R` invokes recursive mode.

Note that it's usually not wise to give more permissions than necessary. Regular files usually should not have execute permissions, as then those could accidentally be called by `bash` and have the (non-shell command) contents be fed into `bash`.

If you want to only set the permissions on directories within a given directory, you need to combine `chmod` with `find`. First use `find` to locate all the directories, and then run `chmod` on those:

```
find directory -type d -exec chmod 777 {} +
```

The `-type d` searches for directories.

The `-exec` indicates that a command should be run on the found filenames.

The `{}` is replaced by the found name. The `+` indicates that multiple names may be replaced into the command line before it is executed.

You also have a file called `>` which sounds like an error somewhere in a script...

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the permission of the folder, not of the files within. Instead, try

```
sudo chmod -R 777 configSite/
```